# EF Core - stored procedure + view

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We're debugging some performance issues in our code and came across something interesting.  We saw the following EF call:

```
await dbContext.CustomView.FromSqlRaw("EXEC [dbo].[MySproc] @param1, @param2 etc.
```

Basically we're calling a stored procedure and returning back on that `CustomView` object (which is a SQL view). Would it be a correct understanding of EF to say that first it's calling the stored procedure and getting the results back, then generating the view (which has it's own joins defined with in it as well)?

Clearly we should just map back to a DTO of some sort but I'm wondering if using this view is causing its own performance issues.

Comment: Did you check if the stored procedure is optimized for performance?

Comment: You execute all the commands inside the procedure, and even you put the select command on the view, and then EF takes the output of the procedure and maps it to the DTO. If there is a performance problem(index ,paging,query,...), it is better to check the procedure at the end of the EF check

Comment: Yes there is certainly optimizations to do on the stored procedure side.  I'm more curious on how EF handles executing the sproc and then mapping to a SQL view...

Answer (score 1):

It isn't mapping it to a view per-se, but rather populating the same entity DbSet defined by the view using the results from the stored procedure.

At the end of the day when you configure an entity to point at a table or view, it is just used as a container and definition for what EF will build SQL to populate, and where it would go to populate it by default. You can tell EF to used a stored procedure or custom SQL as long as the resulting queries are sufficient to populate that object.

Now if you have a view that you would normally use, and someone tried optimizing the read with a stored procedure this may, or may not fully address performance issues they may have been seeing. It really depends on what properties are in this entity, specifically whether there are any navigation properties for related rows in other tables. One of the most common performance issues encountered with EF is due to lazy loading where the view populates an entity, but there are related FKs and navigation properties, where the consumer goes to access these related entities which auto-magically are populated. This comes at a cost of another individual round trip to the database. During development with a limited dataset this often goes unnoticed, but when querying against a growing production database it quickly becomes problematic.

Stored procedures are normally not needed with EF querying when done right, though they do crop up when dealing with legacy systems where some significant legacy business logic resides there and it will be too time consuming/risky to reproduce that in proper EF querying.